# Can you export or share Categories in Outlook 2011?

Tags: mac, email, ms-office

Is there any way to export or otherwise copy Categories, with colors, between Users/Macs?  They also don't yet synch to Exchange 2010, from what I can tell.

I'll likely develop a default new user profile and then run an AppleScript to add the Exchange account based on the currently logged in user's credentials, so I can set up defaults that way, hoping that there's a way to export or copy categories however.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, and unfortunatly No. This is something I spend a few days on recently, and out of interest, it can't be done on the Windows version either. There is no way to keep these categories intact, and it can be a huge problem, especially when sharing items with others since the minute they make a change to a shared item, the categories are overwritten.

You could possibly however use an AppleScript to add them manually, I haven't tried thought.

Comment: It is somewhat possible under Windows with a really ugly script that manipulates a blob in the registry.

Answer (score -1):

we had the same problem. That's why we created the Exchange Category Exporter, which enables you to export contacts based on their given category. For more detailed information check our website at http://software.studio-istanbul.net

If you would like to receive a promotional code just drop me an email and I ll send you one.

Sincerely,

Wolfgang

Comment: The original question concerned exporting the actual categories, not contacts.  Contacts can be filtered, then dragged out from the Contacts window.